# pygtk: howto change background of a gtk.TextView widget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to make the background of a textview widget black and the foreground white.

Been trying the `.modify_bg` and `.modify_fg` methods, but none affect the way this thing looks.

Can anyone suggest anything or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gtk.Widget.modify_text` and `gtk.Widget.modify_base` instead of fg and bg.

Comment: The gtk.widget.modify_base does indeed change the background of the widget, but I cant' find a way to change the color of the text now... so the text is invisible

Answer (score 2):

I resolved some similar manipulating the gtk rcstyles:

```
widget.set_name('mywidget')

# Set mywidget internal style.
gtk.rc_parse_string('\
    style "mywidget"\n\
    {\n\
        attribute1 = value1\n\
        attribute2 = value2\n\
    }\n\
    widget "*.mywidget" style "mywidget"')
```

See [gtk.rcstyle](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkrcstyle.html) at:

bg[state] = color (Sets the color used for the background of most widgets.)

Comment: How about an equivalent of this in python... anyone?

Comment: You can save that in a file (also, you can edit it later of write an editor for it). Reload the stuff using gtk.rc_parse(file_path)